# how to move with a tab key in the userform textboxes and comboboxes in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, tabs, key, userform

I do have 4 text boxes and 4comboboxes and 3 command buttons i want the user to be able to change through them with tab key, how can i program it for the whole user frame and not coding each box separately?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the tab key function:

```
Sub TabKeys()
Dim i as Long

For i = 1 to 4
    UserformName.Controls("TextBox" & i).TabStop = True
    UserformName.Controls("Combobox" & i).Tabstop = True
        If i<4 Then
        UserformName.Controls("CommandButton" & i).TabStop = True
Next i

End Sub
```

If you would like to change the order of the tabs, you can change `TabStop` to `TabIndex` and logically set them by adding a certain number to i:

```
Sub TabIndexChange()
Dim i as Long

For i = 1 to 4
    UserformName.Controls("TextBox" & i).TabIndex = i
    UserformName.Controls("Combobox" & i).TabIndex = i+4
        If i<4 Then
        UserformName.Controls("CommandButton" & i).TabStop = i+8
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dan,but  where should i write the code( in the module,calss..)? and how can i call the sub?

Comment: It should be placed in the UserForm's module. You can either call these subs from an event such as `Userform1_Activate` or place the code directly in the event sub. I would recommend studying the basics of VBA a little more. [This link provides the basics of UserForms](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)